# Unable to use JaudioTagger on Android - NoClassDefFoundError with Jaudio

Tags: android

In my project properties , I added Jaudiotagger.jar as an external archive. Eclipse detects the classes it has.
Here is my sample code :

```
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            Cursor cl = ((SimpleCursorAdapter)l.getAdapter()).getCursor();
            cl.moveToPosition(position);
            String loc = cl.getString(cl.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA));
            try {
                AudioFile f  = AudioFileIO.read(new File(loc));
                Tag tag = f.getTag();
                AudioHeader h = f.getAudioHeader();
                Toast.makeText(this, tag.getFirst(FieldKey.ALBUM), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } 
            catch (Exception e){}
```

When I click on any list item (which is actually an audio file) , the app crashes. Here is the logcat log :

```
02-06 18:19:52.039: W/dalvikvm(32310): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c751f8)
02-06 18:19:52.049: E/AndroidRuntime(32310): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-06 18:19:52.049: E/AndroidRuntime(32310): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jaudiotagger.audio.AudioFileIO
02-06 18:19:52.049: E/AndroidRuntime(32310):    at com.niteesh.album.art.MainActivity.onListItemClick(MainActivity.java:51)
02-06 18:19:52.049: E/AndroidRuntime(32310):    at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:319)
02-06 18:19:52.049: E/AndroidRuntime(32310):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)
02-06 18:19:52.049: E/AndroidRuntime(32310):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1181)
02-06 18:19:52.049: E/AndroidRuntime(32310):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2709)
02-06 18:19:52.049: E/AndroidRuntime(32310):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3464)
02-06 18:19:52.049: E/AndroidRuntime(32310):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
02-06 18:19:52.049: E/AndroidRuntime(32310):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-06 18:19:52.049: E/AndroidRuntime(32310):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-06 18:19:52.049: E/AndroidRuntime(32310):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
02-06 18:19:52.049: E/AndroidRuntime(32310):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-06 18:19:52.049: E/AndroidRuntime(32310):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-06 18:19:52.049: E/AndroidRuntime(32310):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
02-06 18:19:52.049: E/AndroidRuntime(32310):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
02-06 18:19:52.049: E/AndroidRuntime(32310):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I also added `TagOptionSingleton.getInstance().setAndroid(true);` as mentioned in another thread here at SO. And when I click on item then , it says

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jaudiotagger.tag.TagOptionSingleton;`

Can someone help where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did allows the code in Eclipse to compile but doesn't add the jar file to the APK. You need to create a directory in the project root called "libs" and add the jar file to that.  Hope that works for you.

Comment: This jar far contains the compiled files (.class) and not the source. Is that okay?

Comment: Absolutely.  It is more typical for jars to just contain the byte code rather than both byte code and source.

Answer (score 0):

Android does not support Java sound API, even you add it into your project manually, you may meet with a problem of namespace.